# Faster way to calculate intersection over union (IoU) between rectangles and a rectangle

Tags: python, math, torch, loss-function

As a start, I'm calculating the intersection over union (IoU) between two rotated rectangles, say, `rec1` and `rec2`, both of them consisting of 4 2D points.

Luckily, I found an easy way to calculate the IoU between two recs. Like this:

```py
def IoU_of_two_rotatedRec(rec1: np.ndarray, rec2: np.ndarray):

    plg_1 = Polygon(rec_1.reshape((4, 2)))
    plg_2 = Polygon(rec_2.reshape((4, 2)))

    if not plg_1.is_valid:
        from shapely.validation import make_valid
        plg_1 = make_valid(plg_1)

    if not plg_2.is_valid:
        from shapely.validation import make_valid
        plg_2 = make_valid(plg_2)

    inter = plg_1.intersection(plg_2).area
    union = plg_1.area + plg_2.area - inter
    return inter/union
```

However, I'm evaluating a list of candidate recs, `rec_cands`, against a target rec, `rec_tgt`. In this case, a `for` loop is applied: `[IoU_of_two_rotatedRec(each, rec_tgt) for each in rec_cands]`.

Here comes the problem, is there any way to avoid this `for`? Hints:

- All my data is in `torch.tensor`, and I don't think `shapely` can perform a batch operation on tensor data
- The final goal is to calculate the IoUs between a list of candidate recs and a target rec, regardless of the method
- I'll looking forward to a smoothly differentiable solution which could be applied directly on tensor without any type transform.

Comment: Hello. If "IoU" means "intersection over union" and not "i owe you", then I suggest you write "intersection over union" explicitly. Using acronyms like that just makes your question more obscure and makes it less likely that you'll receivre appropriate help. Remember, you've been working with these IoUs all day, so you have them at the forefront of your mind, but the people who read your question are completely out of context.

Comment: In your code you have this line:`union = plg_1.area + plg_2.area + inter`. That's obviously a mistake. It should be `union = plg_1.area + plg_2.area - inter`. Note the minus sign.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid mistake. Thank you for your kind suggestions